# Multiple awaits in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, admob

I have a React Native App where when a user clicks a button, I call a function called `_openInterstitial` which returns 2 promises.

The code is as follows:

```
_openInterstitial = async () => {
    try {
      await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync()
      await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```

When I tap the button twice fast, it returns this error

> An ad is already being requested, await the previous promise.

How do I `await` the previous promise?

Do I need to take the other `await` out into another `try..catch` block?

Is there any other simpler way?

Comment: How do you want it to behave? If you just want to prevent the user from clicking the button during an ongoing request, couldn't you just disable the button when they first click it, and the enabled it after showAdAsync?

Comment: What do you want to happen if `_openInterstitial` is called twice in a row, when the first hasn't had a chance to complete yet? Do you want the second call to resolve immediately, or to resolve at the same time that the first call resolves, or to make a separate request after the first call resolves? (as you can see by the answers, it's not entirely clear what's desired)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My workaround for this is first to `setState({iswaiting: true})`, once the data is retrieved set `iswaiting` to `false`. Once `iswaiting` is `true` just disable the `await` action.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I ended up using :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh yeah forgot that part about react but it's working fine right now so not a worry

Comment: @deadcoder0904 - What incredible timing. I was just coming to SO (33 seconds after your comment above) to say that no, React guarantees that the above will work and not let a second click through (this is not guaranteed for some other events). I [checked with Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/tjcrowder/status/1127200387876970497). :-) So not only does it work, but it's guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 6):

You basically have three options:

1. Disallow calls until the previous call completes, or
2. Queue the calls, starting each one only when the previous one ends, or
3. Have calls to `_openInterstitial` return the promise of the last call if it's still outstanding. So a call may not open a *new* interstitial, it may just return the promise from the previous call.

For #1, you have at least two choices:

If the call to `_openInterstitial` is coming from a UI component callback, depending on the kind of event you're responding to, you can disable that UI component via `setState` as shown in [Max Svid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56088722/157247). For instance, if it's a button and you're responding to `click`, that's guaranteed to work. (I [checked with Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/tjcrowder/status/1127200387876970497).) It's not guaranteed for all events (for instance, `mousemove`), but it is for `click` and similar. The ones where it's guaranteed are listed in `interactiveEventTypeNames` [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/events/SimpleEventPlugin.js).

If not, you'll need to remember that you're in the process of doing this and prevent starting another, something like:

```
_openInterstitialEnabled = true;
_openInterstitial = async () => {
  if (this._openInterstitialEnabled) {
    try {
      this._openInterstitialEnabled = false;
      await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync();
      await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync();
      this._openInterstitialEnabled = true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally, in addition to the guard above, you'd also disable the UI that triggers this function.

For #2 (queueing), remember the previous promise and wait for it to complete before starting the next operation, something like:

```
_lastOpenInterstitial = Promise.resolve();
_openInterstitial = () => {
  return this._lastOpenInterstitial = this._openInterstitialWorker();
};
_openInterstitialWorker = async () => {
  try {
    await this._lastOpenInterstitial;
    await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync();
    await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

or somewhat more simply:

```
_lastOpenInterstitial = Promise.resolve();
_openInterstitial = () => {
  return this._lastOpenInterstitial = this._lastOpenInterstitial
    .then(AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync) // Assuming it doesn't care about `this`, use an arrow function wrapper if it does
    .then(AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync)    // Same assumption
    .catch(error => { console.error(error); });
};
```

or if you like to go back to `async` functions as early as possible:

```
_lastOpenInterstitial = Promise.resolve();
_openInterstitial = () => {
  return this._lastOpenInterstitial = this._lastOpenInterstitial.then(async() => {
    await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync();
    await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync();
  }).catch(error => { console.error(error); });
};
```

In all of those, I've assumed this is within a class of some kind and these are public property declarations using class fields syntax, but it's easy to adjust as necessary if I've guessed incorrectly.

#3 is covered by [CertainPerformance's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56088594/157247).

Comment: Thank you. I ended up disabling the button on function call and enabling after resolving the promise.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to save the ongoing Promise in a semi-persistent variable, and return that ongoing Promise if it exists when the method is called. When the Promise resolves, clear the persistent variable:

```
_openInterstitial = (() => {
  let ongoingProm;
  const getProm = async () => {
    try {
      await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync()
      await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  };
  return () => {
    if (ongoingProm) {
      return ongoingProm;
    }
    ongoingProm = getProm()
      .then(() => {
        ongoingProm = null;
      });
    return ongoingProm;
  };
})();
```

The IIFE is just for the sake of encapsulation, it's probably a good idea, but not necessary.

Comment: This can certainly be an approach for some operations, where you don't care whether you're starting the operation with the call or just getting access to the previously-started operation. Only the OP can say whether that's valid here. I'd think it's usually going to be less common than either just denying the operation or queuing them. :-) Still, good answer.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up disabling the button on function call and enabling after resolving the promise.